# Iterator traits with iterator that returns wrapper object

Tags: c++, iterator, wrapper, traits

I want to design an iterator that returns a wrapper, like this:

```
        VarArgReference operator*() const
        {
            return VarArgReference(state_, stack_index_);
        }
        VarArgReference operator->() const
        {
            return VarArgReference(state_, stack_index_);
        }
```

Now I want to define the iterator traits, e.g. by deriving from `std::iterator`. What I know: This is an InputIterator (read only objects). But I want it also to support Random Access functionality.

So step by step: For InputIterator I need `*i` return "reference, convertible to value_type". So I can simply set reference=value_type=VarArgReference.

Next step is forward iterator. However http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator says "std::iterator_traits::reference must be exactly [...] const T& [for OutputIterator] (It is constant), (where T is the type denoted by std::iterator_traits::value_type)"

So what shall it be? Is my `reference` now really `const VarArgReference&`? This means I'd need to return that type , a const& to a rvalue. And when is the `pointer` used? Do I need to make it `const VarArgReference*` or just `VarArgReference`.

Additional question: ForwardIterator must by default constructible. This would mean that I need to initialize the state with something (invalid?) and probably check and catch that on dereference. Or is it simply undefined behaviour and I can omit the checks?

Note: C++98 and C++11 need to work with this, if this matters

Note2: Using `std::iterator` is deprecated in C++17 which suggest defining the nested typedefs explicitly (see comments). So deriving from `std::iterator` is only **a possibility** to define those, which should however not be used.

Comment: Be careful, `std::iterator` is deprecated in C++17. It doesn't say that reference should be const ref. It depends on whether you support input iterator, output iterator.

Comment: I edited to reflect, that I shortened the text for my case, where it says const ref. I guess in C++17 those types are auto-detected instead? However for C++98 I **need** that.

Comment: @OlzhasZhumabek `std::iterator` is deprecated in C++17? Really? Can you point a reference out for this?

Comment: @skypjack [cppr says so](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator). I would like to know why though.

Comment: @skypjack Found it. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0174r1.html#2.1

Comment: @BaummitAugen, thanks. I couldn't find official paper.

Comment: Ok thanks. I mentioned it in the question for future readers.However using `std::iterator` was only a sidenote in the question as a way to define the traits/types. Any ideas **what** to return and define?

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thanks, really interesting. I've never heard about it before.